# Encountering a logic error while looping to find unique numbers in an array

Tags: java

This is a problem in my textbook for my Java class where the user enters 10 integers. The program is supposed to read all integers and only display the unique numbers (not duplicated) as the output.

-When run the output is:
 Enter 10 numbers: 1 2 3 2 1 6 3 4 5 2
 The number of distinct numbers is 5
 The distinct numbers are: 1 2 3 0 0

-When it should really be:
 Enter 10 numbers: 1 2 3 2 1 6 3 4 5 2
 The number of distinct numbers is 5
 The distinct numbers are: 1 2 3 6 4 5

Since we are in the early stages of the class and understanding the language, our assignment is to complete this using a nested loop. Any help would be appreciated.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class chapter7e5 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        //create Scanner

        System.out.print("Enter 10 numbers: ");

        int[] numberArray = new int[10];
        //create array for all numbers

        int[] distinctArray = new int[10];
        //create array for distinct numbers

        int distinct = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        //for loop to have user enter numbers and put them into array

            numberArray[i] = input.nextInt();

        distinctArray[0] = numberArray[0];
        //first value will be distinct

        for (int i = 1; i < numberArray.length; i++) {
        //loop to go through remaining values in numberArray

            boolean exists = false;
            //create boolean

            for (int j = 0; j < distinctArray.length; j++) {
            //loop to check if value exists already in distinctArray

                if (numberArray[i] == distinctArray[j]) {

                    exists = true;
                    //if value does already exists, then exist = true

                    break;
                    //break out of inner loop

                }
            }

            if (exists == false) {
            //if value is unique then add it to the distinct array

                distinctArray[i] = numberArray[i];

                distinct++;
                //increment variable distinct

            }
        }
        //}

        System.out.println("The number of distinct numbers is " + distinct);

        System.out.print("The distinct numbers are: ");

        for (int k = 0; k < distinct; k++)

            System.out.print(distinctArray[k] + " ");

    }

}
```

Comment: Hello and welcome. You forgot to tell us what the logic error is, i.e. what is the expected output and what you get instead.

Comment: Read [this article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) for tips on debugging your code.

Comment: You shouldn't comment every line of code unless that is a class requirement. Comments should be used to tell why you are doing something or explain a particularly unusual block of code. Don't just repeat what the code already tells anyone who understands it.

Comment: Please do not vandalize your own posts.

Comment: Please don't make more work for others by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange (SE) network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under a [CC BY-SA license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0), for SE to distribute the content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By SE policy, the non-vandalized version is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. Please see: [How does deleting work? …](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221). If permitted to delete, there's a "delete" button below the post, on the left, but it's only in browsers, not the mobile app.

Answer (score 0):

I have the following suggestions:

- Assign each number in the outer loop `numbArray` to  `testNumber` 
  e.g. `int testNumber = numbArray[i];`
- in the inner loop, check that no other number is equal to `testNumber`.  Note that 
  testing is not done when `i == j` since that number was the one assigned to `testNumber`

```
     if (i != j && numberArray[j] == testNumber) {
            exists = true;
            break;
     }
```

- Then in your if clause to determine whether to assign the number or not you can do this

```
  if (!exists) {
     // if value is unique then add it to the distinct array
     distinctArray[distinct++] = testNumber;
 }
```

Note above that is is common practice to not explicitly test boolean against true or 
 false. Since the if statement evaluates on true or false conditions, you can just use the 
value. So `exists` means it is there and `!exists` means it isn't